# how to organize my categories or should I do custom post types for some?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have main pages calling the Main parent and putting recent posts on those pages. What I am having the most trouble with is the Magazine.  I can not seem to just get Spring 2012 to show with it's cover story, features, and departments separate from the Magazine and Fall 2012.

I am thinking I need to reorganize or do this differently any ideas? You can see what I have so far at http://justawebbie.com

My categories so far:

- News

  - Category 1
  - Category 2
- Information

  - category 1
- Magazine

  - Fall 2012
  - Spring 2012
  - Cover Story
  - Features
  - Departments

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code where you pull in the magazine tout?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend going with a custom taxonomy, called "Semesters" (or "Quarter", or "Issue", or whatever makes sense in your context). You can then add "Fall 2012" and "Spring 2012" as Semesters, and assign posts to the relevant one.

(If you're not interested in editing code to set up the custom taxonomy, the [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin is a good one for that.)

From there, you can use any number of approaches to display content: you could create a custom archive page for the taxonomy, or check the taxonomy before displaying posts on the Main parent (and edit the query as needed), or create Pages with custom templates... the sky's the limit, once you have them properly classified.